# KAA demo client creation using cpp sdk

Tags: c++, cmake, kaa

I built CPP SDK on my system and then created binary for demo_client application.
This demo client I created for data collection. When I ran the binary, I got error **bad allocation**. I tried on two systems and same error.

System specification Windows 10 - 64 bit, 8 GB RAM.

I am using KAA IOT sandbox. I am using KAA 10.0.1 version.
I used cmake to build application,

Comment: Could you please post your exact source code as well as server configuration? Also, version 10.0.1 does not exist; and 0.10.1 hasn't been released yet.

Comment: Problem is resolved now. I was trying to build kaa sdk on different system than on which kaa sandbox was present. Is it mandatory to compile kaa sdk on same system where sandbox is present?

Comment: No, that's not a requirement.